# Prove that if $A$ and $B \setminus C$ are disjoint. Then $A \cap B \subset C$

Tags: logic, proof-writing

Is my proof valid? How can I improve it?

Theorem: If $A$ and $B\setminus C$ are disjoint, then $A\cap B\subset C$.
Proof. Suppose $A\cap (B\setminus C)= \emptyset $. Suppose $x$ is an element of $A\cap B$. Since $A\cap (B\setminus C)= \emptyset $ is equivalent to $\forall y\left(y\notin A\vee y\notin B\vee y\in C\right)$, we can plug in $x$ and conclude that $x\in C$, as required.
QED

Answer (score 1):

We can get an easier proof by using your method.

Given that $A\cap(B \setminus C)=\emptyset$

or, $A\cap (B\cap C^c) =\emptyset$

or,$(A\cap B) \cap C^c =\emptyset$  [Due to associativity]

Clearly we can see that $A \cap B$ has no element in $C^c$ then
either $A \cap B$ is an empty set
or has elements in $C$.
In both cases $A \cap B$ is a subset of $C$.